# update a value in TextView when clicking on listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with items. I have developed onitemclick() function with a custom dialog to enter a value. I need to update the listview current item with value we enter in the dialog box.
i have done like this

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        showCustomDialog(view);


        if(quantity>0){
            TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_quantity);
            tv.setTextColor(R.color.white);
            tv.setText(quantity+"");
            quantity=0;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "entered "+quantity , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

showCustomDialog function is

```
protected void showCustomDialog(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dialog;
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_enter_quantity);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText editText;
        editText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.quantity_number);
        Button buttonCancel;
        buttonCancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.quantity_cancel_button);
        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button buttonOK;

        buttonOK = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.quantity_ok_button);
        buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "entered"+editText.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String text=editText.getText().toString();
                if(text=="")
                    text=""+0;
                quantity =Integer.parseInt(text);

                //setQuantity(qty);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

It gets the value and will update on the next item i clicks. How can i correct this problem.

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh listview

Comment: Remove  if(text=="")

         text=""+0;

This may help you. why you are using this?

Comment: when i press simply ok it cause the error. **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""**

Comment: @Raghunandan its refreshing on the value onItemClick of next item with previously entered value.

Comment: This error occur when you try to convert String into Integer which is not number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it.

As below.

write a custom dialog box with an edittext and two buttons for OK and Cancel.

```
buttonOK = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.quantity_ok_button);
        buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text;
                text=editText.getText().toString();
                quantity=text;
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "entered"+editText.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setQuantity(quantity,position);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



void setQuantity(String quantity,int position){

if(!selectedItemsMenu.contains(data))

            // lines ///

            selectedItemsMenu.add(data);

            listMenu.add(position, data);
            Log.e("new list size", selectedItemsMenu.size() + "");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

use

tv.setText(String.valueOf(quantity);

instead of

tv.setText(quantity+"");

Answer (score 0):

if you are using array for list data you have to update the list in exact position.then call adapter.notifiDataChanged().If u want to change it temporally use view.invalidate();